# How to display an image, type "items:autodesk.bim360:File", in HTML, which I uploaded to ACC Files tool using the Data Management API

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I uploaded an image to ACC Files using Data Management API following [this documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) and added a reference between the image and an Issue [following this](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/issues/add-references-to-issues/).

[image: And there's the image uploaded]

All I want is a link where I can put in `<img src="HERE">` to display that image.

With the issue container id I found the container references and then the versions of the file (png image), but in versions response there's no link which I can put in src.

Is there a way to get the blob of the image 64 based? Or there's other way to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this might seem like a trivial feature to ask for, please note that *Autodesk Platform Services* (that the *Autodesk Construction Cloud* product is built on top of) is designed to display complex 3D views and 2D drawings in a specialized Viewer that's provided as a JavaScript library. Displaying a simple raster image in an `<img>` element is also possible but will require more work.

For example, you could point the image element to a custom endpoint on your server which would download the image from ACC (as explained in [this tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/)) and send it back to the client.

Or, you could create a temporary signed URL (using [this endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3download-GET/)) pointing to the actual S3 object that stores your image, and use that URL as the `src` property of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, worked just fine. For those who's reading this, with the image version I can retrieve the storage object id and then ask for the S3 download url with que bucket key and object key